# VBA: Set permission to read Excel file to whole organization

Tags: excel, vba, permissions

So, I've run into a VBA problem. Due to IT policies I can't control read/write access to my Excel files on folder level, but have to do it for each individual file. I have a folder with 15 files, that everyone having access to the folder can access and write in. On a certain date I want to lock these files down, so that only a specific group can write, but the rest can still read.

I'm aware it's realtively easy to do this manually (File->Info->Protect Workbook->Restrict Access), but since I already run a macro for other reasons when we want the files locked down, I'd like for it to do this part too. This is where I run into my problem:

I've figured out how to set the permission for a specific user, using this code

```
Sub set_access()

Dim UserPerm As Office.UserPermission

Workbooks("workbook name").Activate
   Set UserPerm = ActiveWorkbook.Permission.Add("name@company", msoPermissionFullControl)
```

I can loop through this for each person I want to have writing/full access, no problem. There's like fifteen of us and I know who we are.

The thing is I also want everyone in my organization to retain their reading rights. This has it's own button if I do it manually (in the Permission menu that is accessed as mentioned above), but I can't understand how to trigger that setting via vba. I've tried to record a macro of me doing it manually, to see the code, but nothing is recorded. I've also read just about everthing I could find online like four or five times, and what I need simply doesn't seem to be covered.

Does anyone know if this is poosible? Or if it isn't; can I reach the same results some other way?

---

**tldr**: I can set permission by individual, but in addition to this I want to give a general read-only access to my Excel files for anyone in my organization. Can this be done with vba? If so; how?

Comment: Try changing `msoPermissionFullControl` to `msoPermissionRead` for the people who you want to have read only

Comment: Hi Glenn,
As I wrote in my post the problem is I want everyone in the company to have access to read the file. I simply cannot keep a correct and updated list of that many users. In the menus there is a button to give everone reading accesss, and I'm looking for a simular vba-driven solution.

Comment: I've just had a good look at the options in that dialog and it looks like your best option would be to have your IT department setup two user groups for you.  One user group would be read only access and the other group would be the read/write access.  then have them by default add people to the read only group and then you can specify who gets added to the read/write group.  Then in the `Read` field for the file, you list the read only group and in the `Change` field you list the read/write group

Comment: There's two problems with this. 1) I'd have to involve IT and 2) I'm still stuck setting the permissions manually in each file. Also, the option to give everyone in the organization reading rights is already a default Excel option, so IT won't be needed in the first place. If it can't be done with vba I already know the way to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and was looking into it. After all, by using "Everyone" instead of an email address, I was able to set permissions for everyone in my organization. try it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31423727)

Comment: @Taku I'm finally back at work, and this worked perfectly, it was the "" that was needed.